# Shiro and Tomcat AccessLogValve

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, shiro

I'm using `Shiro` (v1.2.1) as security framework, it works perfectly, but in access log for `Tomcat` (v7.0.32) you cannot get remote user in logging when authenticated user access any resource. for my sample web application I used default configuration provided in `Shiro` SVN example [repo](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/shiro/trunk/samples/web/).

```
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Nov/2012:08:22:55 +0200] "POST /pacs/login.jsp HTTP/1.1" 302 - // User here not logged
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Nov/2012:08:22:55 +0200] "GET /pacs/ HTTP/1.1" 200 821 // Here user is accessing protected page, so we got permission.
```

Is there any way this could be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is THE official solution, but it is a solution which works for me:

for the AccessLogValve pattern, use

```
%u - Remote user that was authenticated (if any), else '-'
```

this will print the "guessed user name". If you ask google how tomcat will guess the user name, you'll find something like this:

```
For the user name, the manager uses the Session.getPrincipal() if available; 
if not, it tries the following Session attribute names:
  Login
  User
  userName
  UserName
  Utilisateur
using the given case, lower case, and upper case.  Failing that, it searches for
attributes that are instances of java.security.Principal or
javax.security.auth.Subject.
```

In my case, I just modified the login code to write the user object to the session. Tomcat will invoke a .toString() on this object in order to print the "guessed user name".

If the result from .toString() is not what you want, you can also try to use

```
%{xxx}s xxx is an attribute in the HttpSession
```

in your AccessLogValve configuration in order to print another attribute from your session.

hope that helps.

Comment: "modified the login code to write the user object to the session." would be helpful if you could explain this bit as I have no idea what login code you are talking about or how to write the user object to the session.

Comment: @JimFord : "the login code" means the code which verifies the user. Some kind of loginController or maybe just the first controller which gets hit after a successful login - something where you already have the logged in user which you then can write to the session.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Shiro's native session management, session.getPrincipal() will work as expected.  If you'd like to see this call work in default session management, please open a Jira issue and we'll see if we can fix it asap.

Comment: it would be nice for Shiro to be integrated with other tools, I'll do a ticket soon, thanks for your reply.

Comment: I'm using org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager and not getting any usernames in my access log. can you point me in the right direction?